# Looking to be sure that errors get caught properly in my stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, error-handling, ssms-2012

I'm looking to see if I am able to capture my errors correctly in this stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_UpdateText] 
    (@aID AS INT, 
     @CompanyID AS INT,
     @CompanyName AS VARCHAR(MAX))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result VARCHAR(MAX)

    BEGIN TRY
        SET @Result = (SELECT dbo.[udf_StripHTMLTags](@CompanyName))  -- UDF function that strips HTML tags off my text field

        BEGIN TRANSACTION
            UPDATE __TestTable1
            SET CompanyName = @Result
            WHERE aid = @aid AND CompanyID = @CompanyID

            COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        DECLARE @ErrorNumber INT = ERROR_NUMBER();
        DECLARE @ErrorLine INT = ERROR_LINE();

        PRINT 'ERROR NUMBER: ' + CAST(@ErrorNumber as Varchar(10));
        PRINT 'ERROR LINE: ' + CAST (@ErrorLine as Varchar(10));
    END CATCH
END
Go
```

I'm basically hoping that these BEGIN TRY BEGIN CATCH error capture methods will successfully capture errors, if arise? Any thought?

Comment: I would add a Rollback Transaction in your Catch

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: @marc_s - thank you Marc -- other than does, is it safe to go? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check out [Erland's Guide to Error Handling](http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html)

A suggestion from this inclusive guide would be to change your `CATCH` at a minimum to

```
   BEGIN CATCH
        IF @@trancount > 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION   --roll back the tran
        DECLARE @msg nvarchar(2048) = error_message()  --error message is usually more helpful
        DECLARE @ErrorNumber INT = ERROR_NUMBER();
        DECLARE @ErrorLine INT = ERROR_LINE();
        RAISERROR(@msg,16,1) --RAISE the error 
        RETURN 55555 --return a non-zero to application as non-success
    END CATCH
```

There's a lot more in there which is why it's worth the read.

I almost forgot, `SET XACT_ABORT, NOCOUNT ON` at the top of your proc.

> When you activate XACT_ABORT ON, almost all errors have the same
> effect: any open transaction is rolled back and execution is aborted.
> There are a few exceptions of which the most prominent is the
> RAISERROR statement.

Note that “printing” the error would not store or log it anywhere, like the SQL Server Error log so you wouldn’t “catch” it at all.